# Enumerate json Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I want to parse simple json with following code:

```
func getUsersData ()->(){

    let req : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")!)
    var arrValues : UserModel

    Alamofire.request(req).validate().responseJSON { (response) in 
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let dataJson):
            let json = JSON(dataJson)

            for (_, ob) in json.enumerated(){
                var model = UserModel(name: ob["name"], city: ob["city"], latitude: ob["address"]["geo"]["lat"], longitude: ob["address"]["geo"]["lng"])
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }

}
```

However it cant compile, because it warn me with error -  Type '(String, JSON)' has no subscript members

How to fix it? I want to simply iterate through [simple json](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) and treat it like an array.

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest in                 var model = UserModel(name: ob["name"], city: ob["city"], latitude: ob["address"]["geo"]["lat"], longitude: ob["address"]["geo"]["lng"])

Comment: Please submit to the question the json that you want to cast @EvgeniyKleban

Comment: Also, what is a `JSON` - are you using a library to parse your json or is that a class/struct you have written yourself?

Comment: @deanWombourne it is method from library- https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON, that is convert json response to something like array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess a bit here :)

Your error is `Type '(String, JSON)' has no subscript members`, which is correct - `(String, JSON)` is a tuple. You probably mean to be calling `["name"]` on an instance of `JSON`.

Try removing `enumerated()` i.e.

```
for (_, ob) in json {
```

instead of

```
for (_, ob) in json.enumerated() {
```

Comment: for (_, ob) in json.enumerated() { is work fine, when i call print(ob) it prints each element of json array. Now i want to fill my model using key-value coding like i used to do in Obj-C. But i cant. Please go to: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, i want to create 10 objects for each person and fill it with name city etc.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I've updated my answer - it now works ;) (based on a test I just did in a new project which uses SwiftyJSON to parse the JSON in your question)

Comment: Thank you i will try it tomorrow, really appreciate your help